# Change the image in paintComponent when JButton is being clicked

Tags: java, image, click, jbutton

As the title, I have this code:

```
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("image.png");
        g.drawImage(image, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
```

Now I want to change the image whenever I click a `JButton`.

Is there anyway to change the image in `paintComponent` when `JButton` is clicked?

Comment: *Now I want to change the image whenever I click a JButton.* That's nice.

Comment: Ok, im sorry, i did edit my sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Add a click listener to for the button click event.  When the listener onClick() method is called, change the button image.